# django cron run on openshift

Tags: django, cron, openshift

How do I run cron tasks on openshift PaaS? I used "django_crontab" when I developed on localhost. But openshift has it's own cron cartridge. I used to generate cron on my localhost, it looked like this:

```
#1 1 * * *  /usr/bin/python /home/lucas03/django/openshift/digrin/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 66ba8f74039710e3439ebaa1479f55b2   # django-cronjobs for controller
#1 1 * * *  /usr/bin/python /home/lucas03/django/openshift/digrin/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 3e633e4b25213cc3f8a16cd8909fb269   # django-cronjobs for controller
#1 5 * * *  /usr/bin/python /home/lucas03/django/openshift/digrin/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 01cf5c08eb3017a88cdaabf52561fa2b   # django-cronjobs for controller
```

Than I used hash and run same code on openshift. For example I have put this bash in my .openshift/weekly/watcher

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/lib/openshift/6ff0000UUID/python/virtenv/bin/python /var/lib/openshift/6ff0000UUID/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 66ba8f74039710e3439ebaa1479f55b2
```

But I'm getting `syntax error` or `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. When I try to run that method in ./manage.py shell, it works ok. My way feels stupid. How do you run your cron jobs on openshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/cron-questions#comment-36978
I changed django cron app name and used generated cron hashes from localhost. I generated new ones on openshift and it works. Silly mistake.